# How do you tell if a Quickbooks purchase order is completed/filled/closed in the QBFC?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

- How do you tell if a Quickbooks purchase order is
  completed/filled/closed in the QBFC?

Answer (score 0):

A Purchase Order in QuickBooks is considered closed if either all the items have been received or the lines have been manually closed out. If all the items have been received, then the IsFullyReceived will be true (and the PO will show the "Received in Full" stamp). If the user manually 'closes' the open items, then the PO will be closed and the IsManuallyClosed will be true. Keep in mind that if both are false, it doesn't mean the entire PO is open, as there could have been a partial receiving done against the order.

```
IPurchaseOrderRet poRet = poRetList.GetAt(0);
if(poRet.IsFullyReceived == true || poRet.IsManuallyClosed == true)
{
    // The PO is 'closed'
}
else
{
    // There are still some open items on the PO
    for(int index=0;index<poRet.ORPurchaseOrderLineRetList.Count;index++)
    {
        IORPurchaseOrderLineRet poLine = poRet.ORPurchaseOrderLineRetList.GetAt(index);
        if(poLine.ortype == ENORPurchaseOrderLineRet.orpolrPurchaseOrderLineRet)
        {
            // Check if the received quantity matches the ordered quantity
            if(poLine.PurchaseOrderLineRet.Quantity.GetValue() == poLine.PurchaseOrderLineRet.ReceivedQuantity.GetValue())
            {
                 // Line has been fully received
            }
            if(poLine.PurchaseOrderLineRet.IsManuallyClosed.GetValue() == true)
            {
                 // Line has been manually closed, but could still have
                 // partial received quantity
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Check the GroupLineRet
        }
    }
}
```